# Template Toolkit loop.index in foreach converted to Smarty?

Tags: php, perl, smarty, template-toolkit

I am working on converting a template toolkit project in Perl to PHP with Smarty. However I have been trying to find the equivalent of `[% IF loop.index % 2 %]` within a foreach loop for Smarty. I appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply looking to alternate a display by even/odd in Smarty, which I assume from the '%' modulus operator (though I'm not familiar with Perl):

```
{* Smarty template code *}
{foreach from=$myArray item=foo}
  <tr class="{cycle values="row_even, row_odd"}"><td>{$foo}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
```

Alternatively, if you really care about the index value of an array variable ...

```
{* Smarty template code *}
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
  {if $k % 2}<li>odd</li>{else}even{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense, I just couldn't find it in the docs, since there is a crap load in there.

Comment: Glad I could help -- I know a lot of people who think Smarty should die but I think it's amazeballs.